# React-redux check which action was triggred

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action, react-redux, reducers

I am using react-redux actions for app level state changes.
but not all components should be rendered when certain actions are triggered.
how can I check which action was triggered from any rendering React component?

Comment: It is a little difficult to tell what you mean by your question, but if I understand what you are asking...a console.log() in the action creator before dispatching to the reducer would be the way I would do this in development.

Comment: Thx but, I don't need to log the action for testing, I want to exclude render from specific components when actions that aren't related are triggered.

Comment: @ShaiKimchi React only re-renders those components whose props change. So, for unrelated actions, you don't need to put any condition. Exception being https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#child-reconciliation

Answer (score 3):

Use redux-logger to log all the actions triggered in your dev tools console.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger

It's a middle-ware so you 'll have to add it like so in your store:

```
/* ...import main reducer from wherever */
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(/*..all the other middleares,*/ logger)
);
```

.

Bonus tip: You could integrate [redux-devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools).

It adds a side dock to your site that tracks all the actions. See screen shot below:

[image: redux-devtools in action while side docker tracking page's actions]